# My raycaster renders walls in a really weird way depending on the map size I guess

Tags: gdi+, gdi

I've been writing a raycaster in C++ and to render stuff I use GDI/GDI+. I know that using WGDI to render graphics is not the best idea in the world and I should probably use OpenGL, SFML and etc. but this raycaster does not involve any super-high-level real-time graphics, so in this case WGDI does the job. Besides I probably will be showing this in my school and installing OpenGL there would be a huge pain.

Okay, so the actual problem I wanted to talk about is that whenever I change the map grid from 8x8 to e.g. 8x16, the way that some walls are rendered is pretty bizzarre:[image: Normally rendered walls][image: And then this happens]

If someone can explain why such issue occurrs I would be very happy to discover what's wrong with my code.

**main.cpp**

```cpp
/*
 * Pseudo-code of the void renderer():
 *  Horizontal gridline check:
 *   Set horizontal distance to a pretty high value, horizontal coordinates to camera coordinates
 *   Calculate negative inverse of tangent
 *   Set DOF variable to 0
 *   If ray angle is bigger than PI calculate ray Y-coordinate to be as close as possible to the gridline position and subtract 0.0001 for precision, calculate ray X-coordinate and offset coordinates for the ray moovement over the gridline
 *   If ray angle is smaller than PI do the same as if ray angle < PI but add whatever the size of the map is to ray Y-coordinate
 *   If ray angle is straight up or down set ray coordinates to camera coordinates and DOF to map size
 *   Loop only if DOF is smaller than map size:
 *    Calculate actual gridline coordinates
 *    If the grid cell at [X, Y] is a wall break out from the loop, save the current ray coordinates, calculate the distance between the camera and the wall
 *    Else update ray coordinates with the earlier calculated offsets
 *
 * Vertical gridline check:
 *  Set vertical distance to a pretty high value, vertical coordinates to camera coordinates
 *   Calculate inverse of tangent
 *   Set DOF variable to 0
 *   If ray angle is bigger than PI / 2 and smaller than 3 * PI / 2 calculate ray X-coordinate to be as close as possible to the gridline position and subtract 0.0001 for precision, calculate ray Y-coordinate and offset coordinates for the ray moovement over the gridline
 *   If ray angle is smaller than PI / 2 or bigger than 3 * PI / 2 do the same as if ray angle > PI / 2 && < 3 * PI / 2 but add whatever the size of the map is to ray X-coordinate
 *   If ray angle is straight left or right set ray coordinates to camera coordinates and DOF to map size
 *   Loop only if DOF is smaller than map size:
 *    Calculate actual gridline coordinates
 *    If the grid cell at [X, Y] is a wall break out from the loop, save the current ray coordinates, calculate the distance between the camera and the wall
 *    Else update ray coordinates with the earlier calculated offsets
 *
 * If the vertical distance is smaller than the horizontal one update ray coordinates to the horizontal ones and set final distance to the horizontal one
 * Else update ray coordinates to the vertical ones and set final distance to the vertical one
 * Fix fisheye effect
 * Add one radian to the ray angle
 * Calculate line height by multiplying constant integer 400 by the map size and dividing that by the final distance
 * Calculate line offset (to make it more centered) by subtracting half of the line height from constant integer 400
 * Draw 8-pixels wide column at [ray index * 8, camera Z-offset + line offset] and [ray index * 8, camera Z-offset + line offset + line height] (the color doesn't matter i think)
*/

#include "../../LIB/wsgl.hpp"
#include "res/maths.hpp"
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

const int window_x = 640, window_y = 640;

float camera_x = 256, camera_y = 256, camera_z = 75;
float camera_a = 0.001;
int camera_fov = 80;

int map_x;
int map_y;
int map_s;
shared_ptr<int[]> map_w;

void controls()
{
    if(wsgl::is_key_down(wsgl::key::w))
    {
        int mx = (camera_x + 30 * cos(camera_a)) / map_s;
        int my = (camera_y + 30 * sin(camera_a)) / map_s;
        int mp = my * map_x + mx;

        if(mp >= 0 && mp < map_s && !map_w[mp])
        {camera_x += 15 * cos(camera_a); camera_y += 15 * sin(camera_a);}
    }
    
    if(wsgl::is_key_down(wsgl::key::s))
    {
        int mx = (camera_x - 30 * cos(camera_a)) / map_s;
        int my = (camera_y - 30 * sin(camera_a)) / map_s;
        int mp = my * map_x + mx;

        if(mp >= 0 && mp < map_s && !map_w[mp])
        {camera_x -= 5 * cos(camera_a); camera_y -= 5 * sin(camera_a);}
    }
    
    if(wsgl::is_key_down(wsgl::key::a_left))
    {camera_a = reset_ang(camera_a - 5 * RAD);}
    
    if(wsgl::is_key_down(wsgl::key::a_right))
    {camera_a = reset_ang(camera_a + 5 * RAD);}

    if(wsgl::is_key_down(wsgl::key::a_up))
    {camera_z += 15;}

    if(wsgl::is_key_down(wsgl::key::a_down))
    {camera_z -= 15;}
}

void renderer()
{
    int map_x_pos, map_y_pos, map_cell, dof;
    float ray_x, ray_y, ray_a = reset_ang(camera_a - deg_to_rad(camera_fov / 2));
    float x_offset, y_offset, tangent, distance_h, distance_v, h_x, h_y, v_x, v_y;
    float final_distance, line_height, line_offset;

    wsgl::clear_window();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < camera_fov; i++)
    {
        distance_h = 1000000, h_x = camera_x, h_y = camera_y;
        tangent = -1 / tan(ray_a);
        dof = 0;

        if(ray_a > PI)
        {ray_y = (((int)camera_y / map_s) * map_s) - 0.0001; ray_x = (camera_y - ray_y) * tangent + camera_x; y_offset = -map_s; x_offset = -y_offset * tangent;}

        if(ray_a < PI)
        {ray_y = (((int)camera_y / map_s) * map_s) + map_s; ray_x = (camera_y - ray_y) * tangent + camera_x; y_offset = map_s; x_offset = -y_offset * tangent;}

        if(ray_a == 0 || ray_a == PI)
        {ray_x = camera_x; ray_y = camera_y; dof = map_s;}

        for(dof; dof < map_s; dof++)
        {
            map_x_pos = (int)(ray_x) / map_s;
            map_y_pos = (int)(ray_y) / map_s;
            map_cell = map_y_pos * map_x + map_x_pos;

            if(map_cell >= 0 && map_cell < map_s && map_w[map_cell])
            {dof = map_s; h_x = ray_x; h_y = ray_y; distance_h = distance(camera_x, camera_y, h_x, h_y);}
            else
            {ray_x += x_offset; ray_y += y_offset;}
        }


        distance_v = 1000000, v_x = camera_x, v_y = camera_y;
        tangent = -tan(ray_a);
        dof = 0;

        if(ray_a > PI2 && ray_a < PI3)
        {ray_x = (((int)camera_x / map_s) * map_s) - 0.0001; ray_y = (camera_x - ray_x) * tangent + camera_y; x_offset = -map_s; y_offset = -x_offset * tangent;}

        if(ray_a < PI2 || ray_a > PI3)
        {ray_x = (((int)camera_x / map_s) * map_s) + map_s; ray_y = (camera_x - ray_x) * tangent + camera_y; x_offset = map_s; y_offset = -x_offset * tangent;}

        if(ray_a == PI2 || ray_a == PI3)
        {ray_x = camera_x; ray_y = camera_y; dof = map_s;}

        for(dof; dof < map_s; dof++)
        {
            map_x_pos = (int)(ray_x) / map_s;
            map_y_pos = (int)(ray_y) / map_s;
            map_cell = map_y_pos * map_x + map_x_pos;

            if(map_cell >= 0 && map_cell < map_s && map_w[map_cell])
            {dof = map_s; v_x = ray_x; v_y = ray_y; distance_v = distance(camera_x, camera_y, v_x, v_y);}
            else
            {ray_x += x_offset; ray_y += y_offset;}
        }


        if(distance_v < distance_h)
        {ray_x = v_x; ray_y = v_y; final_distance = distance_v;}
        else
        {ray_x = h_x; ray_y = h_y; final_distance = distance_h;}

        final_distance *= cos(reset_ang(camera_a - ray_a));
        ray_a = reset_ang(ray_a + RAD);
        line_height = (map_s * 400) / final_distance;
        line_offset = 200 - line_height / 2;

        wsgl::draw_line({i * 8, camera_z + line_offset}, {i * 8, camera_z + line_offset + line_height}, {0, 255 / (final_distance / 250 + 1), 0}, 8);

        if(i == camera_fov / 2)
        {wsgl::draw_text({0, 0}, {255, 255, 255}, L"Final distance: " + to_wstring(final_distance) + L" Line height: " + to_wstring(line_height) + L" X: " + to_wstring(camera_x) + L" Y: " + to_wstring(camera_y));}
    }

    wsgl::render_frame();
}

void load_map(wsgl::wide_str wstr, int cell_size = 1)
{
    shared_ptr<wsgl::bmp> map = shared_ptr<wsgl::bmp>(wsgl::bmp::FromFile(wstr.c_str(), true));
    map_x = map->GetWidth();
    map_y = map->GetHeight();
    map_s = map_x * map_y;
    map_w = shared_ptr<int[]>(new int[map_s]);
    wsgl::color color;

    for(int y = 0; y < map_y; y += cell_size)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < map_x; x += cell_size)
        {
            map->GetPixel(x, y, &color);

            if(color.GetR() == 255 && color.GetG() == 255 && color.GetB() == 255)
            {*(map_w.get() + ((y / cell_size) * map_x + (x / cell_size))) = 0;}
            else
            {*(map_w.get() + ((y / cell_size) * map_x + (x / cell_size))) = 1;}
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    wsgl::session sess = wsgl::startup(L"raycaster", {window_x, window_y}); 
    load_map(L"res/map.png");

    while(true)
    {controls(); renderer();}
}
```

**maths.hpp**

```cpp
#include <cmath>

const float PI = 3.14159265359;
const float PI2 = PI / 2;
const float PI3 = 3 * PI2;
const float RAD = PI / 180;

float deg_to_rad(float deg)
{return deg * RAD;}

float distance(float ax, float ay, float bx, float by)
{
    float dx = bx - ax;
    float dy = by - ay;
    
    return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}

float reset_ang(float ang)
{
    if(ang < 0)
    {ang += 2 * PI;}

    if(ang > 2 * PI)
    {ang -= 2 * PI;}

    return ang;
}
```

If someone asks whats **wsgl.hpp** thats just my wrapper library over some WGDI routines and etc.

Comment: @MichaelSohnen I use **wsgl::bmp** (which is defined as **Gdiplus::Bitmap**) to just load the map layout, which is basically transforming white pixels into 0's and anything but white pixels into 1's.

Comment: can you include the pseudocode of your algorithm in the original question?

Comment: I will try my best to write it. Give me a second...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies here:

```
        map_x_pos = (int)(ray_x) / map_s;
        map_y_pos = (int)(ray_y) / map_s;
        map_cell = map_y_pos * map_x + map_x_pos;
```

You need to change the order of operations:

```
        map_x_pos = (int)(ray_x / map_s);
        map_y_pos = (int)(ray_y / map_s);
        map_cell = map_y_pos * map_x + map_x_pos;
```

With your current implementation, you first truncate `ray_x` and `ray_y`, then divide by map_s (which should probably be a floating point value, but is an integer in your current implementation), then truncate again to integer values. Your current implementation needlessly sacrifices precision and will be unpredictable for small `map_s` values.

Additionally, `map_s` seems incorrect. You set `map_s` to represent the total area of your map, but in the above code, you use it like it was the side length of the map.

To be correct, you would need something like

```
#include <cmath>
map_x_pos = (int)(ray_x / sqrtf(map_s));
map_y_pos = (int)(ray_y / sqrtf(map_s));
map_cell = map_y_pos * map_x + map_x_pos;
```

Comment: Unfortunetely it didn't change anything. I wanted to add that just now I discovered that once Y-coordinate of the camera reaches about 920, when I move downwards it magically jumps to about 770 (when it should be decreased by roughly 15). EDIT: **map_s** is of type **int** because the map layout is basically an array of 0's (representing empty spaces) and 1's (representing walls).

Comment: @Kazafka Ok. Also please note that I think `map_s` is incorrect. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Kazafka `map_s` is incorrect since it is the product of `map_x` and `map_y`. You need to store these variables separately when you use them to determine `map_x_pos` and `map_y_pos`. As it is now, you are dividing *length* by *area* which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Using a square root of the `map_s` within map cell coordinates calculation completely messes up the way that all the walls are later drawn on the screen. Now lets say that the map layout is 8x8, so `map_s` is `64`. Ray coordinates ale [64, 64]. Dividing them by `map_s` would result into [1, 1] map cell position, and dividing them by 8 woluld result into [8, 8] map cell position, pretty different, right?

Comment: Sqrt is probably incorrect since that assumes that the map is a square image. You can just write `map_x_pos = (int)(ray_x / map_x)` and `map_y_pos = (int)(ray_y / map_y)` . `ray_x/map_s` and `ray_y/map_s` are incorrect since `map_s = map_x*map_y` in your code.

Comment: Such way of calculating the map cell position results into drawing the environment in that way: [link](https://i.imgur.com/AFVuj3i.png), but when using `map_s` the environment is rendered in a normal way: [link](https://i.imgur.com/Fwe8iwg.png).

Comment: @Kazafka Thanks for showing the result of the updated code. I see now that dividing by `map_s` works and `map_x` doesn't. However that seems to be only because x_offset and y_offset are defined in terms of `map_s`. Why does the march step depend on map size?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I thought exactly the same to myself: what if I'd change the offset coordinates to much smaller values? It seems like it was the case the whole time, but of course, smaller offset coordinates means more cells to test for if they contain a wall, so it takes more time to render the environment.

Comment: @Kazafka I still think you will encounter bugs like the one you posted without some sort of upgrade to your program's overall precision. For raycasters, I always recommend simply drawing a wall as four lines and then using line-line intersections. If you must march a particle, I recommend using a variable step based on the closest distance to the nearest wall ("ray marching). However, for your application, your best bet is probably DDA: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbSee-XM7WA

Comment: I was experimenting with the algorithm quite a bit and my raycaster can finally render the environment without any bugged walls. The only thing I had to do was to set the offset coordinates to 1 (or -1, depends on the `if` statement) and create a variable `map_s_square` equal to the square of the map size. The two `for` loops that scan for a wall now go until `dof` is >= `map_s_square`. Everything seems nice now so thank you for your help!